# Difference between these two maven commands?

Tags: maven, command, maven-2

What is the difference between these 2 maven commands? What does activating a profile really do??

- `mvn deploy -s settings.xml -B -Dmaven.repo.local=/root/maven_repo -P production`

&

- `mvn deploy -s settings.xml -B -Dmaven.repo.local=/root/maven_repo`

Answer (score 0):

A *profile* is a part of the POM that can be activated. If you look into your POM (or parent POM), you will find a profile named `production` that contains some additional stuff.

Comment: in the POM file, under the "production" profile, the deployment path is specified.

Now my question is, If I dont specify the the profile. will the application not deploy?

Comment: I cannot say without seeing your complete POM. It might deploy to some other place specified somewhere in the POM.